# Cross compiling QT 5.14 for raspberry pi 4 [ Could not queue DRM page flip on screen HDMI (invalid argument) ]

Tags: pi-4, gui, cross-compilation, raspbian-lite, qt

I have cross-compiled Qt 5.14 on raspberry pi 4 using ubuntu 18.04
I just followed al the steps of this tutoriel https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TmtN3Rmx9Rk&t=2538s

the code is just right here https://github.com/PhysicsX/QTonRaspberryPi/blob/main/qt5.14.2onRaspberrypi

and after creating RaspberryDemoQml to test

```
~/Desktop/build-RaspberryDemoQml-RaspiQt-Release$ ls
main.o  Makefile  qrc_qml.cpp  qrc_qml.o  RaspberryDemoQml
```

I also checked the file

```
~/Desktop/build-RaspberryDemoQml-RaspiQt-Release$ file RaspberryDemoQml 
RaspberryDemoQml: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=79b829d37b5493d859eab8a5d3534b2d6dfb6d5f, not stripped
```

and everything seems to be okay

and I did `scp RaspberryDemoQml pi@192.168.1.34:/home/pi`

I tried to execute it on my raspberry `./RaspberryDemoQml`

But I got this error

```
Could not queue DRM page flip on screen HDMI (invalid argument)
```

and the system crashed

I am actually working on **raspberry pi os lite**  and I don't want a desktop version

Can someone explain the error for me please ? is that because I don't have GUI ?
do I have to install Xorg ? or It's a QT issue

Comment: No idea if this matches your use case but it may help https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-72538

Comment: Thank you but it is not exactly the same problem :/

Answer (score 1):

Try using this both of these environment variables:

```
QT_QPA_EGLFS_ALWAYS_SET_MODE="1"
QT_QPA_EGLFS_KMS_ATOMIC=1
```

Sources:

- https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=252614
- https://forum.qt.io/topic/118383/can-t-debug-run-a-gui-qml-project-on-a-remote-target-raspberry-pi/16

Comment: thank you for helping I will try it